# HOW TO FILL COMBO BOX IN VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a code to fill my combo box but every time i close the form the list is being doubled, if i have a list from my database of English, Mathematics, Science after i close the form and open it again the list showing is now English, Mathematics, Science, English, Mathematics, Science

HERE IS THE CODE,

```
    Call OpenDB()

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Subject"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read()
        cmbSubject.Items.Add(dr("Subject Name"))    

    End While
    dr.Close()

    Call CloseDB()
```

Comment: Is this vb.net (using Visual Studio) or vba? It can't be both. 

If this is vb.net, do you have the combobox set to store its values in My.Settings? That would cause them to be reloaded when you restart the application and then doubled when you add them from the database.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013

Comment: So in that case, are you saving the combobox values in application settings?

Comment: If i close the form and open it again that's the time the list is doubled. but if i close the Main Form and open again the application it goes back to normal, and vise versa.

Comment: Hi @Blackwood im new in coding in visual studio, thats why i am confused on what to do. Thank you.

Comment: When you close the form do you actually close it with `.Close()` or are you hiding it with `.Hide()`?

Comment: i close it with .close()

Comment: Doesnt matter the IDE logic and syntax is the same...

Comment: Where is the code that you posted located in your application? Which event? And do you know how to use the debugger? Set a breakpoint on `Call OpenDB()` and check the value of `cmbSubject.Items.Count` to see if the combo box is already populated after you close and reopen the form and you might find out why/how your code is being run multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in the method you are using to bind the `combobox`. in each time it binds that's why you are getting duplicate records in the database. to avoid this please clear the `combobox` before each bind, like the following:

```
Call OpenDB()
cmbSubject.Items.Clear ' extra statement added to clear the item collection
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Subject"
cmd.Connection = conn
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read()
    cmbSubject.Items.Add(dr("Subject_Name"))
End While
dr.Close()
Call CloseDB()
```

If you need an alternate method for binding the `combobox` i will suggest you binding with `Dataset`
following is the example code for this :

```
    Dim  SQL As String= "select Subject_Name,Subject_code from Subject"
    Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter(SQL, conn) '<-- This function will Retrieve Data and Return as Dataset together with table name
    Dim myData As New DataSet
    myData.Fill(lobjDataSet, tblName)
    cmbSubject.DataSource = ds_myData 
    cmbSubject.DataMember = "Subject"
    cmbSubject.DataTextField = "Subject_Name"
    cmbSubject.DataValueField = "Subject_code"
    cmbSubject.DataBind()
    myData .Dispose()
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but clearing the combobox will solve the duplication issue but it does not address the fact that the combobox is either being populated multiple times or else the data is being persisted even after the form is closed. You are only hiding the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem.. ONCE AGAIN THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class frmRegistration
    Dim obj As New Entity.Registration
    Dim bus As New Business.Registration



    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        BindingSource1.EndEdit()
        bus.Save(obj)
        RefreshGrid()
        MsgBox("Saved.")
    End Sub


    Sub RefreshGrid()
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = bus.Select()
        BindingSource2.DataSource = dt1
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource2
    End Sub

    Private Sub Registration_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RefreshGrid()
        NewItem()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnNew.Click
        NewItem()
    End Sub

    Sub ResetDis()
        BindingSource1.DataSource = obj
    End Sub

    Sub NewItem()
        obj = New Entity.Registration
        ResetDis()
    End Sub


    Private Sub BindingSource2_CurrentChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingSource2.CurrentChanged
        obj = New Entity.Registration(CType(Me.BindingSource2.Current, DataRowView).Row)
        ResetDis()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: don't just put answers without an explanation. explain the OP what is it and how you made it work.