# Populate vb.net with data from database

Tags: sql, vb.net, xampp

I'm new to programming. How can I populate a combo box from values stored in database? I'm using xampp server as my data source.

Comment: If you can get your data source into an ADO recordset, you can iterate the recordset and add items to the combobox using the comboboxes's AddItem method, one row at a time. Which development environment are you in (i.e. webforms, WinForms, etc.)? The questions is a bit broad but that is one general approach.

Comment: It may also be ComboBox.Items.Add(itm). Here is an example using WinForms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-items-from-a-wf-combobox  Good luck!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOW TO FILL COMBO BOX IN VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132972/how-to-fill-combo-box-in-vb-net)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to determine how to ask a question that is more likely to get answers. One thing I'd suggest is that you need to post some of the code you've tried and where exactly you have a problem so that help can be tailored for you.